# Cannot get SSL to work in Docker container

Tags: apache, ssl, https, docker, openssl

Let me start off by saying that I am no server administrator and there are a great many things I do not know. Because of this I am sure that I have made a mistake somewhere setting up my Docker container, because SSL does not work.

The container is running Apache 2.4 with PHP 5.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 and is linked to a MySQL 5.6 Docker container.

I started with this basic setup from Docker - [Official PHP Repo](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/). Here are the relevant files:

**Dockefile**

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y net-tools
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install sockets

RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod ssl

ADD 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
ADD default-ssl.conf /etc/apache2/sites-anabled/
ADD apache2.conf /etc/apache2/
ADD www-server/ www-server/

EXPOSE 443
```

**000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /www-server/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<Directory /home/www-server/>
    # allow .htaccess overrides to work
    AllowOverride All
    DirectoryIndex login.html index.html index.php
</Directory>

<Directory /home/www-server/client>
    DirectoryIndex home.html
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**default-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/www-server

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/site.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/site.key
        SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/digicert/

     </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**apache2.conf**

```
Mutex file:/var/lock/apache2 default
PidFile /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User www-data
Group www-data
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/2
LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# ports.conf
Listen 80
<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /home/www-server/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

DocumentRoot /home/www-server

AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 combined

<FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

# Multiple DirectoryIndex directives within the same context will add
# to the list of resources to look for rather than replace
# https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex
DirectoryIndex disabled
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

**NOTE**: I have removed non-relevant parts of these files.

To run the Docker container I use this:

```
sudo docker run -v /home/src/ssl-cert:/etc/ssl/certs --name app-gateway --link mysql56:mysql -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -d  app-image
```

Here is a section of the log files:

```
::1 - - [10/Nov/2015:19:26:19 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 152 "-" "Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) PHP/5.6.15 OpenSSL/1.0.1k (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [10/Nov/2015:19:26:20 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 152 "-" "Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) PHP/5.6.15 OpenSSL/1.0.1k (internal dummy connection)"
72.5.190.136 - - [10/Nov/2015:19:26:21 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 0 "-" "-"
72.5.190.136 - - [10/Nov/2015:19:26:21 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 0 "-" "-"
72.5.190.136 - - [10/Nov/2015:19:26:21 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 0 "-" "-"
```

With this error in the browser:

> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

**TL;DR**
I have followed all of the steps that I have found online to install and use my SSL certificates in a Docker container but I have had no success in making it work. Is there anything obvious I've overlooked to make SSL work in a Docker container?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Sometimes, especially when you have been trying to solve a problem for a long time and you're coding in a console window on the command line, you miss the simplest things. Have a look at these two lines in the Dockerfile:

```
ADD 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
ADD default-ssl.conf /etc/apache2/sites-anabled/
```

The `a` is nearly indistinguishable from an `e`, making the misspelling hard to find. The Dockerfile builds the image correctly and *adds* the new directory in the container, then places the configuration file within that directory.

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 www www  4096 Nov 11 15:56 sites-anabled
drwxr-xr-x  2 www www  4096 Oct 23 20:19 sites-available
drwxr-xr-x  2 www www  4096 Nov 11 15:56 sites-enabled
```

Since no error is thrown for an unknown directory and the image builds successfully it will run, but in this case the SSL will not work appropriately.

Comment: Now thats got to hurt

Comment: Hoooo boy, it does indeed. And *several* people missed it @RiggsFolly

Comment: This is why I like IDEs that have spell-checkers :)

Comment: Thanks @JayBlanchard, can you share how you inserted the ssl keys to the server as well?

Comment: I mount the host directory where the SSL certificates are when I start the Docker container @TzookBarNoy

Comment: Thanks, so "etc/ssl/certs/" is mounted on the host that contains the keys?

Comment: That's correct @TzookBarNoy We have more than one container which uses the same certs, so mounting them from the local system is prefereable.

Comment: @JayBlanchard last question... what do you store in "etc/ssl/certs/digicert" as the keys are siblings and not inside it...

Comment: We store the canonical certificate (the certificate authority) provided by our certificate vendor @TzookBarNoy

Comment: just curious why use `ADD` instead of `COPY` for local files?

Comment: @AlexanderMills it is just personal preference. I sometimes include things from a URL, which you cannot do with `COPY`, so I do it for consistency. In this case I could've just as easiily used `COPY`.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't want to 'add' files as other answers had done.
and the HTML files would be installed via a mount to /var/www.
All I needed was the apache server to accept HTTPS (SSL),
redirect HTTP (non-SSL) to HTTPS, and some minor PHP configuration.

Here is what I did in my DockerFile...

```
# Install PHP Apache as the base image
FROM "php:7.3-apache"

# Install ssl-cert (snakeoil) package
RUN set -eux; \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y ssl-cert; \
    : "Clean Apt system" ;\
    apt-get clean; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*; \
    rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /var/log/lastlog /var/log/faillog; \
    rm -f /var/log/{apt/*,alternatives.log,dpkg.log}; \
    :;

# Set up apache with HTTPS redirect
RUN set -eux; \
    : "Time Zone"; \
    ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Australia/Sydney /etc/localtime; \
    : "Apache Changes" ;\
    # enable SSL \
    a2enmod rewrite ssl; \
    a2ensite default-ssl; \
    cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/; \
    sed -i '/<\/VirtualHost>/d'                          000-default.conf; \
    echo 'RewriteEngine On'                           >> 000-default.conf; \
    echo 'RewriteRule . https://%{SERVER_NAME} [R,L]' >> 000-default.conf; \
    echo '</VirtualHost>'                             >> 000-default.conf; \
    :;

# PHP Configuration
RUN set -eux; \
    cd $PHP_INI_DIR; \
    cp php.ini-production php.ini; \
    cd conf.d ;\
    echo "date.timezone=Australia/Sydney"      > date_timezone.ini; \
    echo "session.gc_probability=1"            > session.ini; \
    echo "session.gc_divisor=100"             >> session.ini; \
    echo "session.gc_maxlifetime=1440"        >> session.ini; \
    echo "session.cookie=1440"                >> session.ini; \
    :;
```

Hope you find this helpful